# Что значит "кока"?

Tags: словообразование, этимология

На Кавказе крестную мать называют "кока". Почему?

Comment: Не довелось быть на Кавказе, но обращение к крёстной матери "Кока" неоднократно слышала у нас,в Сибири.

Answer (score 2):

Я нашла это слово всего лишь в двух словарях.

Толковый словарь Даля (1863–1866):
[**ко́ка**](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)
**Ко́кай** м. **ко́ка** ж. *костр.* божат, божатка, крестный отец, мать. *Вот ко́кушка пришла, новг.* крестная.

Словарь русских народных говоров (1978 г., стр. 86):
[7. **Ко́ка**](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/14.pdf), -и, м. и ж. Крестный отец, крестная мать. Нижегор., 1870. Горьк., Яросл., Твер., Влад., Урал., Перм. *Наша-то кока любит свою крестницу. Она мене кокой доводится. Кока гостинцу принес. Кока — это полегче слово, крестна — грубее.* Свердл. Уфим., Иркут. || Ж. Крестная мать. Костром., 1852. Иван., Новг., Волог., Арх., Новосиб., Нерч. Забайк. || М. Крестный отец. *Сегодня кока к нам приехал.* Тунк. Бурят. АССР, 1968.

> Чтобы не пугать детей, мама и кока (тетя Шура была крестной мамой своим племянникам) наивно пытались скрыть от них даже смерть отца.
> [З. В. Юркова. Блокада каждый день](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/blokada-kazhdyy-den-1/viewer) [Ленинград]

География распространения слова обширна и многолетня.

Answer (score 1):

Это старое общерусское название крёстной матери. Малышам проще выговаривать подобные по структуре слова: папа, мама, дядя, тётя, деда, баба, няня, кока.

Answer (score 0):

На Кавказе? В Поволжье такое есть. Означает "крестная", а родственно видимо марийскому "кока" - "тётя (сестра отца или матери)".

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как на Кавказе, но у нас в Нижегородской области всегда крестную называли КОКА. У моей мамы была кока Вера, потом её все звали кокой (младшая сестра мамы и мы их дети), в моей жизни есть кока Люба, у сестры есть кока Нина. А я сама для своих крестников кока Юля. Причём мы, даже на улице при посторонних, никогда не говорим тётя, только кока. Например, моя любимая кока Люба.